# Stenciljs - Background image css path

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs

Im trying to add a background image on my scss file but I could not make it work.

This is the code on my scss file:

> ```
>   background-image: url('./assets/images/Square.svg');
> ```

And when I use my component on my other app this is the path I get:

http://localhost:4200/assets/images/Square.svg

which is not my component path.

I tried to add ‘/dist/collection/assets/images’ but it did not worked

I found this bug report https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/923 1 but it is closed and it seems that was not fixed.

Comment: try [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/background-image-for-page-on-ionic/52466/8)

Comment: During build, stencil copies everything from the assets path to the output, which should be served under `/assets`. Have you tried absolutely referencing your image, i. e. `background-image: url('/assets/images/Square.svg');` (without the leading dot)?

Comment: I tried both comments and none have worked. It looks to be a common problem since `npm start` will show the picture and we continue developing. Until the component is imported in a real life app where none of its assets are being copied into the `build` dir. Finally [documentation](https://stenciljs.com/docs) doesn't help at all.

Comment: Using an absolute URL is not a solution, because the component can be included on a page that isn't at the root. Or hosted in a place other than the current web server (e.g. unpkg.com)

Comment: @arturorv00 did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: What I did was to move my assets to the consumer app. so basically I did a task that copy the /assets folder from the webcomponent and paste it on the app I am using to consume the webcomponent, does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `background:url(data:image/gif;base64,...` with base64 image instead of using a relative or absolute url.

Here is a URL for more information
https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Answer (score 0):

Stencil by default copy assets folder in www.

[Stencil assets config docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/config/#copy)

I think you just can remove the ./ from the image path and just directly refer image in scss file.

```
background-image: url('assets/images/Square.svg');
```

This should work. I have tried and this is working.

[Working Code Sample](https://github.com/RiteshSRajput/stencil_assets)

Comment: Can you please try to give the URL in scss directly. do not append ./ in image path because it will expect image in domain root folder not in component's folder